# Add value Y to Column B if Column A is within range(X)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:56,
                 x_1 = runif(56), x_2 = runif(56), x_3 = runif(56),    
                 x_4 = runif(56))
```

I am trying to add a value (let's say 0.5) to a new column of this `df` if `id` is equal to any of the following numbers: 1:27, 32, 44:50, 54, 55, 56, and then add another value (let's say 0.4) to all of the remaining rows that have an `id` value not included in the aforementioned range. Then I will multiply each other cell in the row by these new values.

I know I can do this with an `ifelse` or `mutate` statement, but that would require typing out each individual number that id could be equal to which I'm hoping is unnecessary.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
IDs <- c(1:27, 32, 44:50, 54, 55, 56)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(id=1:56,
#                  x_1 = runif(56), x_2 = runif(56), x_3 = runif(56),    
#                  x_4 = runif(56))
IDs <- c(1:27, 32, 44:50, 54, 55, 56)
```

We can first assign `multi` to be one of 0.4 or 0.5 based on the `id`:

```r
tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(multi = if_else(id %in% IDs, 0.5, 0.4)) %>%
  tail()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#      id    x_1     x_2   x_3   x_4 multi
#   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    51 0.333  0.740   0.602 0.547   0.4
# 2    52 0.347  0.733   0.197 0.893   0.4
# 3    53 0.398  0.536   0.535 0.490   0.4
# 4    54 0.785  0.00227 0.180 0.172   0.5
# 5    55 0.0389 0.609   0.452 0.543   0.5
# 6    56 0.749  0.837   0.317 0.961   0.5
```

From this, we can easily multiple that value against a subset of columns using `dplyr::across`.

```r
tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(multi = if_else(id %in% IDs, 0.5, 0.4)) %>%
  mutate(across(x_1:x_4, ~ multi * .)) %>%
  tail
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#      id    x_1     x_2    x_3    x_4 multi
#   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    51 0.133  0.296   0.241  0.219    0.4
# 2    52 0.139  0.293   0.0788 0.357    0.4
# 3    53 0.159  0.214   0.214  0.196    0.4
# 4    54 0.392  0.00114 0.0898 0.0858   0.5
# 5    55 0.0195 0.304   0.226  0.272    0.5
# 6    56 0.374  0.418   0.159  0.481    0.5
```

The two steps could be combined into a single `mutate`. They could even be combined into a single assignment without it if you no longer need `multi` around.